# Carry Cookie accross to another directory

Tags: php, html, mysql, cookies

UPDATE:

I have set a cookie in the admin directory on my site, See below:

```
$expire=time()+3600;
setcookie("loggood","YES", "/", $expire);
```

Then in the public_html directory of my site, i am trying to read this cookie using the below:

```
     <?php
 $user=$_COOKIE["user"];
 $logood=$_COOKIE["loggood"];
 setcookie("user", $user, time()+10000);

  if ($loggood=="YES")

 {
 echo"Logged In";
 }
 else
 {
 echo"Not Logged In";
 }
 ?>
```

However, weather i am logged in or not it still shows `Not logged in`

Please help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: make sure the domain/subdomain is not changing between your 2 test pages.

Comment: @chris He has different directories for where the cookie is being set, and where it is being received. He needed to change the cookie directory to '/', although having a different domain/subdomain would to it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the cookie, do it like so

```
setcookie($name, $value, $time, "/", "", 0);
```

The / in the 4th option means that the cookie will run through the whole site. If you want it just to run through one directory, do

```
setcookie($name, $value, $time, "/directoryname", "", 0);
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for this, i have updated my code above, please could you advise?

Answer (score 1):

For the first file, you have to do

```
$expire=time()+3600;
setcookie("loggood", "YES", $expire, "/", "", 0);
```

I'm deciding to ignore the user cookie, because you didn't mention it, but I suggest you do it in the same format as the code I entered above. Please don't edit any of the code in that function beyond $expire.

Comment: Brill, Thiis works great... One final question, how do i end the cookie?

Comment: end the cookie? like remove it? set the time to a negative number.

Comment: like $expire=time()-3600; and set the cookie again